# How do i access data from multiple models/controllers in my view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to create a view that will create a subcategory.

In order to create this view I inherit my model for subcategories in the view in order to access the required attributes etc.

Now one of the attributes I wish to set on my subcategory object is a reference to a normal Category.

However I am not sure how to populate my dropdownlist with category items since I am already using the model of subcategories.

My question is, what would be the best way to access a `SelectList` of category objects in my subcategory view.

I've considered using partial views or perhaps transfering the data in my `ViewBag` or `ViewData`.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a `ViewModel`. This is basically a class that you use to bring together all the pieces of the various models required for your view.

It might look something like:

```
public class CategoryListingsVieWModel
{
   public IList<ISubCategory> Subcategories{get;set;}
   public IList<ICategory> Categories{get;set;}
   [...] // Any other data your view needs
}
```

This then becomes the model for your view which your pass from your controller.

Comment: I was thinking about this approach as well. But f.e. both Category and Subcategory has a title attribute. wont this cause some kind of problems?

Comment: It shouldn't cause any problem. If you have a single category and a single subcategory in your view model, you'll be accessing them as `Model.Category.Title` and `Model.Subcategory.Title`. That's pretty standard stuff.